# Why can't I declare a using statement for a namespace, but can directly declare the namespace before the type?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering if someone has seen this scenario before or has any suggestions to what might be causing it. I have a custom class called `Dashboard` that exists inside a project called `Dashboard.Data.Client`. Within that same project, if I try to reference the class's namespace such as:

```
using Alliance.Dashboard.Data.Client.Models;
```

then I cannot use the type `Dashboard`. However, anywhere I need to use `Dashboard`, I can type out the fully qualified name and it works fine. Example:

```
Alliance.Dashboard.Data.Client.Models.Dashboard myDashboard = new Alliance.Dashboard.Data.Client.Models.Dashboard();
```

A few notes I'm sure you will be wondering:

1. If I just type `Dashboard` in a class, and then try to resolve it, the option isn't available.
2. I have seen this issue before if there are conflicting namespaces. In such case, a fully qualified name must be given. That is not the case here. There is no conflicting namespaces.
3. Other classes resolve just fine within this project. As a matter of fact, here is a scenario: from `IDashboardRepository` this problem exists trying to declare `Dashboard` just as I described. `IDashboardRepository` is in the same project but in a different namespace: `Alliance.Dashboard.Data.Client.Interfaces`. However, the reverse works fine. In other words, I can use the interface namespace as a using statement within `Dashboard`, but not `Dashboard` inside the interface without the fully qualified name.

For reference, here is the code for my `Dashboard` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Alliance.Dashboard.Data.Client.Models
{
    public class Dashboard
    {
        public System.Guid DashboardID { get; set; }

        public string DashboardName { get; set; }

        public byte[] Instance { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public byte[] Concurrency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "then I cannot use the type Dashboard" -- what is the compiler error you receive when you try?

Comment: More importantly, can you come up with a short reproducible example?

Comment: Do you have another class or anything else called `Dashboard` in either your current Namespace or other using imports? You have to explicitly declare which one you want to use if it is ambiguous. Only other way around it is to Alias those dupes in the using.

Comment: See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: Holy heck. How did I freaking miss that? I going to jump off a freaking bridge. You can seriously begin talking about me in past tense. You guys led me to it immediately. The problem is that the class name and project name are identical. The compiler thinks I have started typing the beginning of a namespace instead of the class name. I am a freaking moron. Sorry to bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I feel pretty stupid on this one. Simply put, the namespace and class name are the same. The compiler thinks that I have entered the beginning of the namespace directory instead of the class name. Thanks again for taking time to help another knuckle head.